# What causes commerce order numbers to skip a number?

Tags: commerce, 9

On a Drupal 9 / Commerce 2 site, order numbers (not ID's) are incremental for completed orders. I've got a site though where - very rarely - an order number is skipped: 55, 56, 57, 59, 60, 61, ...

Is there a way to check what happened to order number 58?
I'm exporting orders to SAP, and SAP does not like non-incremental order numbers.

I have checked:

- Commerce Log table: does not show anything related to the missing order numbers that I can see
- Http returns from payment provider: nothing between order number 57 and 59 chronologically

Comment: What kind of payment gateway are you using? Possible the order number is being assigned to the order on two separate page requests causing the apparent skip.

Comment: @RyanSzrama: now there's a theory I hadn't considered that sounds plausible. 
Perhaps a combination of server-to-server confirmation + user return from gateway.

I'll look into it. Thanks!